# deploying jersey rest web service in wildfly

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, wildfly

I am unable to invoke rest web service using jersey deployed in wildfly.

Where as the same code is executing fine in my local eclipse.

Below is the error that I am getting :

> 2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr]
>   (default task-4)  at
>   com.sun.jersey.impl.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:147)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:364) 2018-03-06
>   15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)  at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:355)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$100(WebResource.java:57)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:317)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   com.oracle.methods.OracleDataUpdateMethod.execute(OracleDataUpdateMethod.java:118)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   com.documentum.mthdservlet.DmMethodRunner.runIt(Unknown Source)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   com.documentum.mthdservlet.AMethodRunner.runAndReturnStatus(Unknown
>   Source) 2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   com.documentum.mthdservlet.DoMethod.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   com.documentum.mthdservlet.DoMethod.doPost(Unknown Source) 2018-03-06
>   15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR
>   [stderr] (default task-4) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.impl.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.getHeaderValue(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:213)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,880 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.impl.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.writeHeaders(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:194)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,895 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.impl.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:177)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,895 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.impl.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:145)
>   2018-03-06 15:27:45,895 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   ... 38 more

Comment: How did you install Jersey? By default WildFly uses Resteasy for it's JAX-RS implementation.

Comment: Hi James, it is very delayed reply that I doing now. Actually, I flipped my approach to restful web services. so I have avoided using Jersey. BTW, do we need installation for Jersey. I remember that I have just added Jersey jars while trying to implement the web service

Comment: If you're just using JAX-RS then you don't need to install or provide any JAX-RS dependencies. WildFly will use RESTEasy for it's JAX-RS implementation.